# Python get the height or number of lines for a string given a font and container width

Tags: python, user-interface, openpyxl

I am trying to generate a speadsheet using openpyxl that contains data in the following format. where all cells should be wrapped for their given width.

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----+
| Long text | More Long text h..| num |
| Here....  +-------------------+-----+
|           | More Long text h..| num |
+-----------+-------------------+-----+
```

The problem is that the row heights are fixed and the text gets cut off.

openpyxl doesn't seem to have a auto row height feature, so I would have to calculate what the height or line-count is for a given font and width.

I have looked around for packages that do this but with no luck. Any ideas or approaches to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
# this generates the example above
from openpyxl.styles import *
from openpyxl import Workbook

alignment = Alignment (
    horizontal='center',
    vertical='center',
    wrap_text= True,
)
font = Font(name='Calibri',
    size=11,
)

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws.merge_cells("A1:A2")
ws["A1"] = "Long text here..."

long_string = "More Long text here..."

ws["B1"], ws["B2"] = long_string
# sets a fixed width for column `B`
ws.column_dimensions["B"].width = 50
# sets a height for row 1
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = get_row_height(text=long_text, width=50)

ws["C1"], ws["C2"] = 0

def get_row_height(text, width):
    # this magic function returns how many lines `text` takes up
```

Before posting this question, I tried playing around with tkinter, but the result wasn't exactly what I wanted

```
from tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Y, END, Text, font as f
root = Tk()
font = f.Font(family="Calibri", size=11)
line_height = font.metrics("linespace")
T = Text(root, width=30, font=font)
T.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
T.insert(END, "THIS IS A VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT")
num_lines = int(T.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
```

Comment: Could you add your code to your question.

Comment: It would be nice to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with your question. Have you checked out [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate)? It can output in a variety of formats and really easy to use.

Comment: @MarkyPython see edit

Comment: @Igor, I have checked out tabulate, but I don't believe it exports to excel or does cell merging/styling which is what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: For a tkinter solution, do the cells need to be editable or do you just need to display the data? The tkinter Label widget can be told to wrap at a specific width (ie: the width of the column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the formatting that openpyxl can apply is less than you hope. Particularly row heights and column widths are **entirely** dependent upon the reading application and rely on things like the operating system.

Furthermore, openpyxl follows the specification rather than Excel so, for example, applying a style to a Row or ColumnDimension is an instruction for Excel to format **future** cells not existing ones. The specification contains no information **whatsoever** about how merged cells should be formatted. A bug report was submitted over a year ago but we're still waiting for clarification.

To achieve the best results you should be prepared to dissect an existing worksheet and recreate the styles from it. NB. this is a bit tricky due to the use of pointers in the OOXML format.